# How to use syscall to change vDSO content

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, system-calls, vdso

I am trying to implement a `syscall` on `x86` that is able to modify the content of `vDSO`. Given `vDSO` content is read-only for userspace, I believe a `syscall` is needed. Otherwise it will cause segmentation fault. However, I can't do it successfully at this moment.

## My plan:

### syscall in `kernel/sys.c`

```
extern struct vdso_data _vdso_data[CS_BASES] __attribute__((visibility("hidden")));
SYSCALL_DEFINE1(foo, int, num) {
    struct vdso_data *vdata = _vdso_data;
    vdata[0].__unused = num;
    return 0;
}
```

The `syscall` will read the `_vdso_data` which is declared in `arch/x86/include/asm/vvar.h` and defined in `arch/x86/include/asm/vdso/vsyscall.h`.
Then it will modify the variable `__unused` into some number input by the user.

### vDSO in `arch/x86/entry/vdso/vclock_gettime.c`

```
#include <asm/vdso/vsyscall.h>
notrace int __vdso_query()
{
    struct vdso_data *vdata = __arch_get_k_vdso_data();
    return vdata[0].__unused;
}
```

I know it's a bad idea to define something unrelated to time in a timing fucntion, but this is what I'm testing right now. The `__vdso_query()` function will read the data and return the value of the `__unused` variable.

### Testing plan

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define SYS_foo 548
extern int __vdso_query();
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int before = __vdso_query();
  printf("Before syscall: %d\n", before);

  int num = 10;

  long res = syscall(SYS_foo, num);

  int after = __vdso_query();
  printf("After syscall: %d\n", after);
  return res;
}
```

#### Expected results

I want to see `0` before the `syscall` and `10` after the `syscall` returned by `__vdso_query()` since the `syscall` will change the `_vdso_data[0].__unused` if everything follows the plan.

#### Current results

For now, the content is always `0` regardless of the `syscall`.

### Questions

#### How to access `_vdso_data` properly

There are 2 ways I tried to access the `_vdso_data`: `__arch_sync_vdso_data()` and `extern`.

1. When I tried to use `__arch_get_k_vdso_data` function where defined in `asm/vdso/vsyscall.h` to access the `_vdso_data`, I encounter some variable redefinition errors. If I include `vsyscall.h` in both `kernel/sys.c` and `arch/x86/entry/vdso/vclock_gettime.c`, it seems `DEFINE_VVAR(struct vdso_data, _vdso_data);` will be called twice and leads to redefinition error of `_vdso_data`. I tried to put `#ifndef`, `#def`, and `#endif` macros around it but the error still exists.
2. Another thing I tried is only declaring the `_vdso_data` as `extern` variable shown in the `syscall` implementation. The redefinition error is gone if I do this. The code compiles and runs properly without error or segmentation fault, but the result doesn't change.

### `__arch_sync_vdso_data()` function

I read some [example usages](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/time/vsyscall.c#L130) in the kernel source code a little bit and I find people use `__arch_sync_vdso_data` function to write the `_vdso_data` in the end. However, I think this function is actually empty in the `generic-asm` and the only definition I can find is on `Arm`. Not really sure how this will work on `x86` and is it needed.

It's really hard to find vdso resources online and I've read all the recent posts. I would really appreciate the help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out `syscall` is doing the right work and the problem is how to access the `vDSO` data.

In fact, `__arch_get_vdso_data` is the right function to access vDSO data. It returns a pointer which can be further dereferenced to access the data like `__arch_get_vdso_data()->__unused`.

On the other hand, `__arch_get_k_vdso_data` never works and I suspect the `_k_` in the function name indicates that this function can be only used in kernel space.